# Too many redirects on ingress-controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setup an Ingress Controller based upon:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws
It works fine for ELB, but for some reason, if I set the following in NLB:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

then I am getting a `Too many redirects` error.
If I set the above to false then I can access both HTTP and HTTPS separately but there is no redirection.

In my Service annotations for NLB I have:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:12345:certificate/xyz
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-2019-08
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      appProtocol: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      appProtocol: https
```

for ELB where it works ok I have:

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:12345:certificate/xyz
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: elb
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: tohttps
      appProtocol: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      appProtocol: https
```

I've tried many combinations but I can't get NLB to act in the same way like with ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If backend protocol set to "ssl" everything works fine, except the fact that we're doing double TLS offloading for no reason (on NLB first, then on ingress). If backend protocol set to "tcp", we'll get "Plain HTTP request sent to TLS port" error. If we map https to http port to address the above then HTTP -> HTTPS redirects stop working.

So to make it working with NLB I needed set the backend protocol to ssl: `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: ssl`
and then:

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
```

Comment: I have exact same issue when switching from ELB to NLB. The above solution works perfect for me. Thanks very much

Comment: But do you know why setting the TLS offloading at the ingress (by setting the backend protocol to ssl) solve the redirect issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing the `appProtocol: https` and offload SSL at the LB level

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:12345:certificate/xyz
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-2019-08
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: HTTP
```

You can check config at : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

Also, check from AWS console LB having **80** and **TLS 443** Listeners.

SSL offloading & terinating : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-https-traffic-eks-acm/

Comment: No, that doesn't work either, I've tried this earlier and I want SSL to be terminated on NLB not in ingress.